# Backslashes in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a quick Python script to do a bit of inspection on some of our Hibernate mapping files. I'm trying to use this bit of Python to get the table name of a POJO, whether or not its class path is fully defined:

```
searchObj = re.search(r'<class name="(.*\\.|)' + pojo + '".*table="(.*?)"', contents)
```

However - say pojo is 'MyObject' - the regex is not matching it to this line:

```
<class name="com.place.package.MyObject" table="my_cool_object" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">
```

If I print the string (while stopped in Pdb) I'm searching with, I see this:

```
'<class name="(.*\\\\.|)MyObject".*table="(.*?)"'
```

I'm quite confused as to what's going wrong here. For one, I was under the impression that the 'r' prefix made it so that the backslashes wouldn't be escaped. Even so, if I remove one of the backslashes such that my search string is this:

```
searchObj = re.search(r'<class name="(.*\.|)' + pojo + '".*table="(.*?)"', contents)
```

And the string searched becomes

```
'<class name="(.*\\.|)MyObject".*table="(.*?)"'
```

It still doesn't return a match. What's going wrong here? The regex expression I'm intending to use works on regex101.com (with just one backslash in the apparently problematic area.) Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: @Keatinge - Why isn't it matching, then, when I just have one backslash? The regex should be good based on that site. Also - if it's just MyObject, it matches, but if it's com.place.package.MyObject, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this:

```
re.search(r'<class name="(.*\\.|)' + pojo + '".*table="(.*?)"', contents)
```

The the first part of the pattern is interpreted like this:

```
1. class name="    a literal string beginning with c and ending with "
2. (               the beginning of a group
3.   .*                zero or more of any characters
4.   \\                a literal single slash
5.   .                 any single character
6. OR
7.                     nothing
8. )               end of the group
```

Since the string you're searching for does not have a literal backslash, it won't match.

If what you intend is for `\\.` to mean "a literal period", you need a single backslash since it is inside a raw string: `\.`

Also, ending the group with a pipe seems weird. I'm not sure what you think that's accomplishing. If you mean to say "any number of characters ending in a dot, or nothing", you can do that with `(.*\.)?`, since the `?` means "zero or one of the preceding match".

This seems to work for me:

```
import re
contents1 = '''<class name="com.place.package.MyObject" table="my_cool_object" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">'''
contents2 = '''<class name="MyObject" table="my_cool_object" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">'''
pojo="MyObject"

pattern = r'<class name="(.*\.)?' + pojo + '.*table="(.*?)"'

assert(re.search(pattern, contents1))
assert(re.search(pattern, contents2))
```

Comment: Yeah, ending it with a pipe and doing what you said function the same way. As for the rest of your comment, in the second half of my post I showed that it also does not worth with just r'\.' either, so that's not the problem I'm running into.

Comment: @TrevorThackston: the backslash is definitely at least part of the problem. I've updated my answer with a working example, showing that the pattern matches both a fully qualified name and a relative name.

Comment: You're right - I just mean that I said I had already tried it. Anyways, I figured out the problem it was having on my real dataset. A few of the tables have 'mutable="false"' after the table, so it was getting confused and showing errors. Figured out how to fix that, though.

Comment: @TrevorThackston: that's one of the many reasons why trying to parse HTML with regular expressions is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

On [Pythex](http://pythex.org), I tried this regex:

`<class name="(.*)\.MyObject" table="([^"]*)"`

on this string:

`<class name="com.place.package.MyObject" table="my_cool_object" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">`

and got these two match captures:

1. `com.place.package`
2. `my_cool_object`

So I think in your case, this line

```
searchObj = re.search(r'<class name="(.*)\.' + pojo + '"table="([^"]*)"', contents)
```

will produce the result you want.

---

About the confusing backslashes – you add two and then four show up, on the Python documentation [7.2. `re` — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) it explains that `r''` is “raw string notation”, used to circumvent Python’s regular character escaping, which uses a backslash. So:

- `'\\'` means “a string composed of one backslash”, since the first backslash in the string escapes the second backslash. Python sees the first backslash and thinks, ‘the next character is a special one’; then it sees the second and says, ‘the special character is an actual backslash’. It’s stored as a single character `\`. If you ask Python to print this, it will escape the output and show you `"\\"`.
- `r'\\'` means “a string composed of two actual backslashes. It’s stored as character `\` followed by  character `\`. If you ask Python to print this, it will escape the output and show you `"\\\\"`.

Comment: The problem is with the first part of the regex, not the second, and you changed the first part such that it works on qualified path names only.

Comment: @TrevorThackston I don’t know what you mean by ‘qualified path names’, so please clarify. Give me a couple examples of things you want the first part to match.

Comment: I would like it to match these two:

`<class name="com.place.package.MyObject" table="my_cool_object" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">`

and

`<class name="MyObject" table="my_cool_object" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true">`